# How can I add links/launchers icons to Gnome 3 panel?

Tags: gnome, panel

I'm a Ubuntu 12.10 user, and I want to know how to place link icons in the Gnome 3 panel. Does anybody know how to solve this matter ?

P.S.: In the Gnome panel I don't have the on/off button and the other icons on the upper right corner of the screen. Please help me ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Run the app, right click on the icon in the panel, select dock to launcher.

Comment: I solved the problem. I opened ubuntu with "gnome 3 classic (no effects)" and then I drag the link icon on the upper panel.